# FireBase onChildAdded() triggers onChildRemoved()

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to understand how the two are related. From the docs:

> onChildAdded event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The listener is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data.

And that:

> The onChildRemoved event is triggered when an immediate child is removed. It is typically used in conjunction with onChildAdded and onChildChanged events. The snapshot passed to the event callback contains the data for the removed child.

So techincally i was expecting that the two events are triggered separately based on their roles: that is, `onChildAdded` will be triggered when i add new data while `onChildRemoved` is when i delete a `child` from the `nodes`.

However, when i add data this is what i log:

```js
14:47:39.649 31305-31305/com.myapp D/addData_: onChildRemoved called
14:47:39.649 31305-31305/com.myapp D/addData_: onChildAdded called
```

`onChildRemoved` is called first before `onChildAdded`!! What's worse is that the data disappears from my `listview`. Someone help me understand what it is i'm doing wrong.

This is my data structure:[image]

And my firebase ref:

```js
 ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("sales/" + getId() + "/" + getDateTime());
    
        //limit to the last data
        final Query lastSale = ref.limitToLast(1);
        //add on child event listener
        lastSale.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                //get the data from firebase and add it to our model
               
                MyModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyModel.class);
                String firebase_key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
 Log.d("addData_", "onChildAdded called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Log.d("addData_", "onChildChanged called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("addData_", "onChildRemoved called");
             
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d("addData_", "onChildMoved called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I commented out his line and it worked!

```js
 //limit to the last data 
        final Query lastSale = ref.limitToLast(1);
```

Comment: limitToLast is not solving above problem you described So techincally i was expecting that the two events are triggered separately based on their roles: that is, onChildAdded will be triggered when i add new data while onChildRemoved is when i delete a child from the nodes.

Comment: For some reason I was replicating that reaction over and over. I still cannot explain it. But the above action gave me the expected results.

Comment: have you resolved this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765033/firebase-android-childeventlistener-triggered-onchildremoved-before-onchildadd

Comment: Indeed i have friend :)