# Firebase Android ChildEventListener Triggered onChildRemoved() before onChildAdded() When new data added

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding new data to Firebase as following code

```
updateChildren(childUpdates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError,   DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

        }
}
```

And following code for ChildEventListener

```
fb.child(Organizations.class.getSimpleName().toLowerCase()).limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(crudListener);

ChildEventListener crudListener = new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onChildAdded "+ dataSnapshot.toString()+" \n String "+s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onChildChanged "+ dataSnapshot.toString()+" \n String "+s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onChildRemoved "+ dataSnapshot.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onChildAdded "+ dataSnapshot.toString()+" \n String "+s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

};
```

issue is when I am creating new data then **onChildRemoved()**  triggered before **onChildAdded()**

I am not removing any child but **onChildRemoved()** triggered every time when new child is created

following Web(javascript) code it's working fine

```
 firebase.initializeApp(config);


 var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('organizations').limitToLast(1);
 commentsRef.on('child_added', function(snap) {
    $('pre').text("child_added: "+JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 2));
 });

 commentsRef.on('child_changed', function(snap) {
    $('pre').text("child_changed: "+JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 2));
 });

 commentsRef.on('child_removed', function(snap) {
    $('pre').text("child_removed: "+JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 2));
 });
```

here is my Database structure. I am creating new child under **organizations**

[image]

Pleaes help me how to fix this issue

Comment: can you post the `childUpdates`'s value, the database structure, and the reference where `crudListener` is attached ? the onChildRemoved() will be triggered if any child has the value changed to `null`

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: how do you attach `crudListener`? any filter method such as `limitToFirst`, `limitToLast`, etc?

Comment: .child(Organizations.class.getSimpleName().toLowerCase()).limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(crudListener);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned you're using `li‌mitToLast(1)` when attaching `crudListener`. That's actually how it works.

from [Quer#limitToLast() reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)

> The `limitToLast()` method is used to set a maximum number of children to be synced for a given callback. If we set a limit of 100, we will initially only receive up to 100 `child_added` events. If we have less than 100 messages stored in our database, a `child_added` event will fire for each message. However, if we have over 100 messages, we will only receive a child_added event for the last 100 ordered messages. As items change, we will receive `child_removed` events for each item that drops out of the active list, so that the total number stays at 100.

If you use `li‌​mitToLast(1)`, the `onChildRemoved()` will be called if a new child is inserted to maintain the limit (which is 1), and then `onChildAdded()` called the new child.

If you don't want this behavior, remove the `li‌​mitToLast(1)` method

**EDIT:**
If you want to keep using `limitToLast(1)`, then you have to do checking if an organization entry is really removed from the database or it's from the limit behavior.

```
@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    dataSnapshot.getRef().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                // remove this organization item from the RecyclerView
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if didn't use li‌​mitToLast(1) then it will return all childs any idea

Comment: then, ignore the `onChildRemoved()` method, don't implement anything inside that method :)

Comment: I can't  ignore onChildRemoved

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: but with web version is not happening. is it Firebase Android SDK  bug... ?

Comment: I am using pagination with RecyclerView (without Firebase UI) . For first time data fetching i am using addListenerForSingleValueEvent and for event listener i am using addChildEventListener

Comment: what is not happening? the function callback didn't trigger in on('child_removed' after inserting new child?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124510/discussion-between-munish-kapoor-and-wilik).

Comment: onChildRemoved will always be called before onChildAdded after a new data is inserted if you're using limitToLast(1) in your query

Comment: Great explanation Wilik! I often say that Firebase queries result in a "sliding window". If you add a child on one end of the window, the last child on the other end of the window is removed.

Comment: thank you @FrankvanPuffelen, now I know another way to explain Firebase query to others :)

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you find an even better way to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar "unexpected" behaviour connected to `onChildRemoved`, when I used filtering operators `orderByChild("someKey").equalTo(someValue)`.

Being offline I added new item. When connection appeared, item I added was synced with firebase database remotely. Unexpectedly `onChildRemoved` was called for the added value.. When I removed the operators `orderByChild("someKey").equalTo(someValue)`, `onChildRemoved` wasn't trigerred. But `onChildChanged` was called instead.

Hope it will save someone a few hours.